# Cannot find name 'async'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am moving my methods to a class, but when I am trying to make an interface for one of the methods I get this error.

This the code for the interface:

```
       interface IUsers {
      checkRoles(requiredRoles: string[]) => async (_req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void>;
      checkIsVerified(_req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void>;
      isAuthenticated(_req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void>;
    }
```

And this the method I am trying to write in the interface:

```
 checkRoles = (requiredRoles: string[]) => async (_req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
    logger.development.info({ event: 'begin', involved: 'check_roles' });

    const { tokenInfo: { userRoles: roles } } = res.locals;
    const userRoles = _.values(_.mapValues(roles, 'name'));

    try {
      if (!(userRoles.some((userRole: string) => requiredRoles.includes(userRole)))) {
        throw errors.create('PermissionsError', { userRoles, requiredRoles, message: 'Not enough permissions to access this endpoint.' });
      }

      logger.development.info({ event: 'end', involved: 'check_roles' });
      next();
    } catch (exception) {
      logger.development.info({ event: 'failure', involved: 'check_roles' });
      next(exception);
    }   }
```

The error I get is for the first method in the interface:

> `any Cannot find name 'async'.ts(2304)`
>
> Blockquote

Answer (score 2):

In an interface you cannot place the async keyword. The async keyword only wraps the method into a promise so just stating the method returns a promise should be enough.

```js
type Handler = (_req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) =>  Promise<void>

interface IUsers {
      checkRoles(requiredRoles: string[]) : Handler;
      checkIsVerified(_req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void>;
      isAuthenticated(_req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void>;
}
```

Comment: So what part should I get rid of?

Comment: I added an example of how to do it in the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: The purpose of the `async` modifier is purely an implementation detail. It enables use of the `await` keyword within the _body_ of a function and also causes the function to return to `Promise` regardless of its implementation.